# Using rakefile to compile C files

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile, cflags

I encounter a problem while compiling C files using rake. I am able to define my constant in the rakefile, and print out the value of this constant in my C file.

This works fine, compiles, links and executes as expected, when the defined constant is an integer.
But, when a string is defined as constant in the rake file, i'm not able to compile. I'm sure i'm missing the right syntax here.

Here's my `rakefile.rb`

```
require 'rake/clean'

CLEAN.include('*.o')
CLOBBER.include('*.exe')

source_files = Rake::FileList["*.c"]
object_files = source_files.ext(".o")

TEST_CONST="A STRING" #### <---- This causes problem

task :default => "test_app"

task :clean do
    sh "rm -rfv *.o"
end

desc "Build the binary executable"
file "test_app" => object_files do |task|
    sh "gcc #{object_files} -o #{task.name}"
end


rule '.o' => '.c' do |task|
    sh "gcc -c #{task.source} -DVAR=#{TEST_CONST}"
end
```

This is my C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    printf("Running main\n");
    printf("VAR: %s\n",VAR);
}
```

This is the error log:

```
<command-line>:0:5: error: ‘A STRING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:6:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAR’
     printf("VAR: %s\n",VAR);
                        ^~~
<command-line>:0:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:6:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAR’
     printf("VAR: %s\n",VAR);
                        ^~~
rake aborted!
```

In a makefile, i would add something like this, to CFLAGS: `-DSTRVAR=\"$(VAR)\"`
I have no idea how to do this using rake, i.e passing a string constant as compile flag. Has anyone come across this specific problem before, and could give some ideas?

**EDIT 1:**

I changed the asignment to `TEST_CONST="'(A STRING)'"` as suggested, and this is the error im getting, im running on Ubuntu Linux.

```
gcc -c main.c -DVAR='A STRING'
main.c: In function ‘main’:
<command-line>:0:5: error: ‘A’ undeclared (first use in this function)
main.c:10:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAR’
     printf("VAR: %s \n",VAR);
                         ^~~
<command-line>:0:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:10:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAR’
     printf("VAR: %s \n",VAR);
                         ^~~
<command-line>:0:7: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘STRING’
main.c:10:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘VAR’
     printf("VAR: %s \n",VAR);
                         ^~~
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [gcc -c main.c -DVAR='A STRING'...]
/home/abel/Projects/rake_test/rakefile.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => default => test_app => main.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

`TEST_CONST="\'A STRING\'"` would work.

It’ll result in:

```
sh "gcc -c #{task.source} -DVAR=#{TEST_CONST}"
```

interpolated to:

```
gcc -c test.c -DVAR='A STRING'
```

Comment: Youre right in saying that how it manifests on compiling. but i still get a rake aborted failure.

Comment: This should be induced. I copy-pasted your snippets and made sure it compiles and runs successfully.

Comment: I have updated the post. I'm a bit surprised it worked for you, may be i am missing some Ruby dependencies or so. Are you running on Windows or?

Comment: No, I am on Linux.

Comment: This worked for me: `TEST_CONST='\""A STRING"\"'`. Maybe, it has something to do with GCC version, mine ist 7.3.0

Comment: I have updated the answer since yours is indeed bulletproof.